# why LISTAGG operator not use to update bulk update?

Tags: jsp, oracle11g

```
 <%
        try
        {
            String employee_id3=request.getParameter("txtemployeeid");
     if(request.getParameter("btnPunchout")!=null)
         {
      Timestamp date_out=java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(java.time.LocalDateTime.now());
           Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
              Connection con3=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.18.114.213:1821:godb","xe","Spacess");


                 String time_out_history="UPDATE EMPLOYEE_LOGIN_TIME T1 SET T1.TIME_OUT_HISTORY=(SELECT LISTAGG(time_out,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY time_out) FROM EMPLOYEE_LOGIN_TIME WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID='" + employee_id3+"' and trunc(time_out)=trunc(SYSDATE))";
               PreparedStatement ps5=con3.prepareStatement(time_out_history);
               ps5.executeUpdate();

    %>
      <%

         String Update_Timeout="update EMPLOYEE_LOGIN_TIME set time_out=? where Employee_id='"+employee_id3+"' and trunc(punch_date)=trunc(SYSDATE)";
              PreparedStatement ps3=con3.prepareStatement(Update_Timeout);
               ps3.setTimestamp(1,date_out);
                  ps3.executeUpdate();
                  %>

    <%  String Date1="UPDATE EMPLOYEE_LOGIN_TIME T1 SET T1.WORKING_HOUR=(SELECT to_timestamp (to_char(TIME_OUT))- to_timestamp (to_char(TIME_IN)) AS WORKING_HOUR FROM EMPLOYEE_LOGIN_TIME WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID='" + employee_id3+"' and trunc(punch_date)=trunc(SYSDATE))";
              PreparedStatement ps8=con3.prepareStatement(Date1);
                   ps8.executeUpdate();  
                   %>

    <%

         out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
   out.println("alert('You are Successfully logout for the day');");
   out.println("location='EmployeeLogin.html';");
   out.println("</script>");

       }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    %>
```

Now my question is what whenever i click logout button 2 and 3 no. query working fine but in first query it is store only last logout details i want to show time_out_history column multiple logout data as he done for particular day like

> 19-APR-18 04.12.38.676000 PM,
>
> 19-APR-18 04.13.38.676000 PM,
>
> 19-APR-18 04.14.38.676000 PM,
>
> 19-APR-18 04.15.38.676000 PM

and so on...

Comment: Indian guy,all the three query is `update` no query at all,you need to add more of your code with a well format

Comment: @lucumt: more means what exactly?

Comment: more of your code,within the code you added now,we can not analysis it

Comment: i updated my code what actually i want to do on logout button i want to update current time,log in and logout time difference and last logout history that is logic

Comment: What's TIME_OUT_HISTORY column? date or varchar ?

Comment: @user7294900: it is varchar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you expect a specific date format, so you need to use [to_char function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm) with the specific format you want:

```
LISTAGG(to_char(time_out,'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF AM'),',')
```